# Can I asynchronously prefetch to the GPU in tensorflow (1.4) using a two-variables approach?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, tensorflow

As far as I'm aware there is still no asynchronous prefetching of data between CPU/GPU in tensorflow 1.4.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5722

I am trying to code this functionality myself as an exercise in understanding.

The following code attempts to implement this process:

1. The next batch is stored in a `data_var` variable.
2. Process some operations (aka train a model) which gets its batch from the variable `data_var`, in this example just execute `myop` which depends on `data_var`.
3. A `prefetch` OP assigns the next batch from a Dataset object (CPU based) into `temp_var` a gpu-based variable.
4. Using `tf.control_dependencies(...)` wait for `myop` and `prefetch_op` to complete, then assign `temp_var` to `data_var`

This doesn't appear to work. The TF profiler shows that `myop` is not asynchronously processed with the `MEMCPYHtoD` process as was hoped for.

I had expected that the two OPs, `myop`, and `prefetch_op` would run asynchronously because there are no dependencies between them.

[image]

Here is the code I used to run this test. It will run stand-alone.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import timeline
import numpy as np
import os

sz = 2000
x = np.random.rand(sz, sz)

def gen():
  yield x

# Dataset
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=gen, output_types=tf.float64)
ds = ds.repeat()
ds = ds.prefetch(2)
iterator = ds.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

# Prefetch to GPU OPs - this is exepected to happen asynchronously
temp_var = tf.Variable(np.zeros((sz, sz)), name='temp_var', dtype=tf.float64, expected_shape=(sz, sz), trainable=False)
data_var = tf.Variable(np.zeros((sz, sz)), name='data_var', dtype=tf.float64, expected_shape=(sz, sz), trainable=False)
prefetch_op = tf.assign(temp_var, next_element)

# Trivial math operation for timing purposes
myop = tf.sqrt(data_var, name='myop')

# Final prefetch to GPU operation, copy data from temp_var to data_var
with tf.control_dependencies((myop, prefetch_op)):
  assign_op = tf.assign(data_var, temp_var)

# Open session, initialize, and run 1 iteration to warm the prefetch buffer
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run((myop, assign_op))

# Main sess.run with profiling on
tf_options_profiler_on = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
tf_run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
graph_result = sess.run((myop, assign_op), options=tf_options_profiler_on, run_metadata=tf_run_metadata)

# Write profile data
chrome_trace = timeline.Timeline(tf_run_metadata.step_stats).generate_chrome_trace_format()
os.makedirs('/tmp/profile', exist_ok=True)
with open('/tmp/profile/tf_profile_step.json', 'w') as f:
  f.write(chrome_trace)

print(graph_result)
print('Writing profiler output to /tmp/profile')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In tensorflow 1.7 the Dataset API now has `prefetch_to_device`.

Documentation:

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/prefetch_to_device

Github discussion:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13610#issuecomment-364331935

It looks like another option is mentioned further down in the above Github discussion (now closed) called a `MultiDeviceIterator`.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13610#issuecomment-411893139